# Did Eric Trump say Melania is smarter than Michelle Obama?

Tags: united-states, quotes

The facebook account [StopTheWorldTheTeaBaggersWantOff](https://www.facebook.com/StopTheTeaParty/) shared [this image](https://www.facebook.com/StopTheTeaParty/photos/a.502129386487003.92449663.502122049821070/1253863107980290/?type=3&theater), which as of this writing has 24.7k shares, 4.2k "reactions" (formerly "likes"), and 2.6k comments:

[image]

saying

> Melania is way smarter than Michelle Obama. She's totally intelligent. Anyone can go to law school but being a model takes a lot of brains. She had to rely on her smarts to get so successful.

Searching for "Eric Trump" and "Melania is way smarter" doesn't turn up anything,<sup>1</sup> so it seems likely to be a joke image rather than a genuine quote. Is the quote genuine?

---

<sup>1</sup> *Well, it didn't when I posted the question. Naturally, that search now finds this question and its answer.*

Comment: As the source is by its own admission a satirical site which "is NOT meant to be taken seriously", this should be closed as not notable.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard The test for notability isn't what the site calls itself. The test for notability is whether many people believe the claim.

Comment: @Dawn I don't think it's been shown that many people believe the claim. I'm unable to find this post on Facebook, so there's no way to tell how many shares it has (the account itself has 73,000 likes, but I don't know if that's a lot, and someone liking a satirical account in no way implies that they believe what it says). Unless it's reposted many times with many likes of its own, I don't think it's notable.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard That is a better argument for non-notability (in that it is applying the proper notability test).

Comment: @iamnotmaynard (and all): I've updated the question with a link to the original image and the shares/reactions/comments stats as of this writing, so those more familiar with the standards of the site can judge notability. Frighteningly for those of us who would like to see critical thinking applied regularly, the comments indicate a fair number of people taking it at face value. Ugh. (Along with some saying "I don't think these quotes are legit" and "Is this a joke?" and such. Thankfully.)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The [page involved](https://www.facebook.com/StopTheTeaParty/info/?entry_point=page_nav_about_item&tab=page_info) is not a serious quote site. It is a satirical page and openly admits to be so:

> This page is for entertainment purposes. It is NOT meant to be taken seriously. It is primarily satire and parody with a mix of political memes and messages.

[Snopes' other entry](http://www.snopes.com/eric-trump-fake-speech-quote/) on a similar post by the same page makes the same point, and links to a number of other hoaxes perpetrated by the same author(s).

Comment: Yeah, given that Snopes entry, I think we can be certain it's just a joke. Good find!